# vb.net & office: Unable to cast COM object of type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass'

Tags: vb.net, excel

I'm developing a vb.net application and it should open and handle a excel file.
The problem is that in my pc (and the same could happen in other pc where it could be installed) I have Visio version 2013 and Office (excel, word, etc..) version 2010. Integrating excel in vb is so simple because more or less automatic, done in few steps.. but in the same time so stupid: calling interop.Excel functions, it addresses to the newest version of office intalled (2013), but I don't have excel for that version!
I searched a lot on the web about this issue, and every where I found the solution of deleting a registry key, well, it works fine, but every time I use Visio, it seems the registry key is recreated again.

My questions are:

- can I select which version of excel I would like to link my application?
  I can understand that fixing the version I should handle any office versions
  manually.. but maybe I prefer doing this..
- can I copy a dll in the application folder to be sure that the app uses that 
  version? I tried with Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll and Office.dll but still the issue

I don't want to follow the way of deleting the registry key programmatically, is not safe in my opinion..
I can't believe that the integration between office and .net is so stupid that is not able to use the right version of excel installed!! 
;-P

Code:

```
        Dim fileTest As String = FilePath

    Dim APP As New Application
    MsgBox(APP.Version)

    Dim oSheet As Excel.Worksheet = Nothing
    Dim workbook As Excel.Workbook = Nothing
    Dim IndexFound As Integer = 0
    Dim StartRow As Integer = 10
    Dim DateSelected As String = ""
    Dim resultOK As Boolean = False

    Try

        workbook = APP.Workbooks.Open(fileTest)

        oSheet = workbook.Worksheets("Activities")

        APP.DisplayAlerts = False

        oSheet.Range("A2").Value = "test"
        oSheet.Range("B3").Value = "Ciao"

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Error: " + ex.Message)

        If Not resultOK Then
            If Not workbook Is Nothing Then
                workbook.Close()
                While System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(workbook) > 0
                End While
                workbook = Nothing
            End If
            oSheet = Nothing
            workbook = Nothing
            APP.Quit()
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(APP)
            APP = Nothing
            GC.Collect()
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()
        End If
    End Try

End Sub
```

[image: Reference excel interop]
[image: Reference Office core]

Thanks
Andrea

[image]

Comment: Weird, when adding reference to your project, you should see a list of all the excel versions and you can select the one you want to work with.

Comment: Not really, I mean, of course, in my project I have only Excel 2010 installed, so the reference for sure is to that version. The problem is that running, it seems it is looking the last Office version and that searching Excel of it..

Comment: I am not sure, can you post your code?

Comment: Yes, here the code I'm using, please be more specific, I'm pretty sure this code can't help you.. which code you mean?

Comment: How do you define your excels objects?

Comment: I added 2 images, I can find references.. the only doubt I have is that the office core version is 14 but it seems the path somehow refers to version 15.. any idea? do you need more?

Comment: Just for your information, I deleted the reference of Office core and it still building.. it means it was not necessary in the application, but the issue still.

Comment: You have defined APP as Application and not Excel.Application. Could it be that it's using the reference to Microsoft.Office.Core and not the reference to Microsoft.Office.Application ? - I suggest you use Excel.Appliction.

Comment: Even adjusting as suggested, the problem still. Just to be clear, if I delete the registry key, without touching the code it works fine! I'm not sure it's something in the code, I mean, my original question was: can I define which version of excel it should refer?

Comment: I added the picture of registry key that removing it (1.8) all will work fine.

Comment: So.. no way to fix the problem without removing the registry key?